# DataTables custom filters range filtering - how to remove commas from numbers?

Tags: javascript, datatables, filtering

I'm trying to implement the DataTables Custom Filters / Range Filtering fucntionality, as detailed on this page: https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html ).

It works fine except that the column I'm filtering includes comma separators in the numbers that are displayed in the table, and that screws up the filtering.

It seems to be treating the comma and any digits that follow it as non-existent, so the number 1,234 would be treated as 1.

I thought it would be easy to add a line to remove these commas after this line:

```
var dit100 = parseInt( data[3], 10 ) || 0;
```

I've tried various ways to replace the commas with nothing, including this:

```
dit100 = dit100.replace(/,/g, '');
```

... and other methods too.

However, in each case, adding that one additional line stops the DataTables script from working.

What's weird is that the above replace command does work in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pudqpr2t/

I know I'm probably doing something stupid here, but I can't spot what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please provide an example of the markup / table.  Apparently you have other issues than just type confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but isn't it because you are trying to do the replace on an `int`?

Perhaps try

```
var dit100 = data[3] || 0;
dit100 = dit100.replace(/,/g, '');
dit100 = parseInt( dit100 , 10 );
```

You then do the replace on the string before converting it to `int`

Comment: Thanks,

I tried what you suggest, which makes a lot of sense, but it's still breaking the script.

I added a few alerts, and only the first of the three is being displayed:

    var dit100 = parseInt( data[3], 10 ) || 0;
    alert(dit100);
    dit100 = dit100.replace(/,/g, '');
    alert(dit100);
    dit100 = parseInt( dit100 , 10 );
    alert(dit100);

That would imply it doesn't like the line with the replace function, but it still looks like valid JavaScript to me.

Comment: try using, `var regex = new RegExp(',', 'g');` and `dit100 = dit100.replace(regex, '');`.  Apparently some browsers do not like `/,/g` and prefer a `RegExp` object

Comment: @Mark if it solved your problem, please accept it as the answer.  Glad I could help :)